# IIS website cannot access over internet using eternal ip

Tags: windows-7

I have created asp.net project(test website), I have published this project using visual studio 2013. I have setup this site in IIS, using local host and local ip i.e. 192.168.1.3:80 I am able to view this site even from the other computer in Lan i can access this website but not able to access from internet (using external ip i.e my public ip). I have forwarded port 80 in my router as well as in inbound and outbound rules. dont know what I am missing. I dont have static IP but I just want to test this first before buying a static IP.

Comment: Are you trying to access the public IP from *within* your local network?

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:-

- Make sure your firewall is not blocking port 80 from public access.
- Check your public IP address with a site like [this one](http://whatismyipaddress.com/).
- You may not be able to use loop-back, so try accessing from a computer outside your intranet (at office or at a friend's), or use a proxy.
- If you cannot connect, use a port scanner like [this one](https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap) to show the ports open on your IP.

Make sure the machine running IIS has a fixed IP on your intranet; otherwise, the port forwarding will become invalid if the IP address changes.